# Websocket close event not fire on server - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ws

I have use ws Plugin in nodejs application for the web-socket implementation.

When I close the ws connection from the client, ws close event should call.
It is working on local but not work on server.

Here is the sample code:

```js
exports.Initialize = function (server, app) {
 wss = new WebSocket.Server({
  server
 });
 app.on('upgrade', wss.handleUpgrade);
 setWsHeartbeat(wss, (ws, data, binary) => {
  if (data === '{"kind":"ping"}') { // send pong if recieved a ping.
   ws.send('{"kind":"pong"}');
  }
 });
 wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, req) {

  clients.push({
   ws,
   type: location.query.type
  });

  ws.on('message', function (response) {

  });

  ws.on('close', function (e, c, b, x) {
   let index = clients.findIndex(x => x.ws === ws);
   if (index > -1) {
    clients.splice(index, 1);
   }
  });

  ws.on('error', function (e) {
   let index = clients.findIndex(x => x.ws === ws);
   if (index > -1) {
    clients.splice(index, 1);
   }
  });
 });
};
```